# ERROR while trying to run my java game

Tags: java

Below is the code that i received in the console when trying to run my game download the code [here](http://visualbasicstutorials.weebly.com/uploads/2/0/7/9/20797922/gamecode.zip).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
at com.comli.blah.rainofwrath.graphics.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:22)
at com.comli.blah.rainofwrath.game.<init>(game.java:38)
at com.comli.blah.rainofwrath.game.main(game.java:123)
```

Code:

```
public class Screen {

private int width, height;
    public int[] pixels;
    public final int MAP_SIZE = 64;
    public final int MAP_SIZE_MASK = MAP_SIZE - 1;

    public int[] tiles = new int[8 * 8];

    private Random random = new Random();

    public Screen (int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int[width * height]; // 50,400

        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt(0xffffff);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public void render(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int yy = y + yOffset;
        //  if (yy < 0 || yy >= height) break;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int xx = x + xOffset;
            //  if (xx < 0 || xx >= width) break;
                int tileIndex = ((xx >> 4) & MAP_SIZE_MASK) + ((yy >> 4) & MAP_SIZE_MASK) * MAP_SIZE;
                pixels[x + y * width] = Sprite.grass.pixels[(x&15) + (y&15) * Sprite.grass.SIZE];
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The error message is specific. Have you tried to debug the code before posting the question here?

Comment: Don't link you code like that. Figure out which parts of relevant (start with `Screen.java` line 22), and post those directly into your question

Comment: `8*8=64` but `64*64 > 64`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in the `tiles` array. It has 64 (8 * 8) elements during initialization, whilst by specifying `i < MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE` (`MAP_SIZE = 64`) as `stop-rule` at you loop you are trying to go beyond this limit. I belive it should be:

```
public int[] tiles = new int[MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE]
```